# In elisp How do I extract value from a variable

Tags: elisp, emacs23

I'm on the first exercise section (Emacs Lisp Intro) and I'm not getting it; 3.12 exercises:

Write a function that tests whether the current value of
`fill-column' is greater than the argument passed to the function, and if so, prints an appropriate message.

I have:

```
(defun is-fill-equal (number)
   "Is fill-column greater than the argument passed to the function."
   (interactive "p")
(if (= fill-column number)
    (message "They are equal.")
  (message "They are not equal."))
```

No matter what I try I get this error:

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable number)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing one parenthesis at the end. Try:

```
(defun is-fill-equal (number)
   "Is fill-column greater than the argument passed to the function."
   (interactive "p")
   (if (= fill-column number)
       (message "They are equal.")
     (message "They are not equal.")))
```

The reason for the error message is that you probably `C-x e` at the end of the function definition. As you are missing one parenthesis Emacs thinks that the expression you want to evaluate is `(if (= fill-column number) ...)` and `number` is unbound in that context.

Comment: Thanks. I tried several variations but kept repeating the same mistake.